# php - why difference between two times always wrong using these methods?

Tags: php, time

```
$time1 = time();
$time2 = mktime(date('H')+1, date('i'), date('s'), date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));
$diff = $time2 - $time1
echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $time)."<br/>";
echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $new_time)."<br/>";
echo date('H', $diff);
```

Output:

```
2013/09/03 09:25:52
2013/09/03 10:25:52
02 //which should be 1
```

Why is the $diff always different from the correct answer by 1?

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of `date()` expects a timestamp, you're giving it the difference of two timestamps - in this case 3600. `var_dump(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 3600));` is "1970-01-01 02:00:00".

Look into the `DateTime` and `DateInterval` classes. Your code's equivalent looks like this:

```
$time1 = new \DateTime();
$time2 = (new \DateTime())->modify("+1 hour");
$diff = $time1->diff($time2, true);
var_dump($diff->h); // int(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You getting only seconds between times. Try divide to `3600`

```
echo round($diff/3600); // 1
```